# How to remove timestamp using regex from a date string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

New to regex.

Need regular expression to match strings like `T17:44:24Z` from parent strings like `2015-12-22T17:44:24Z` using javascript regex.

Once match is found will replace it with null or empty space.

To be specific i am trying to remove the time stamp from date string and obtain only date part.

Please help me in this

Comment: Replace `/T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z/` with empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z
or
T(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}Z
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU4zN3/1)**

In case your `T` and `Z` are dynamic the, you can use:

```
[A-Z]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[A-Z]
```

Code

```
var re = /T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z/g; 
var str = '2015-12-22T17:44:24Z';
var subst = ''; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex on this. You just split the string by `T` and get the second element from array, which would be `17:44:24Z` in your case.

```
var date = '2015-12-22T17:44:24Z';
var result = date.split('T')[1];
```

If you also want to preserve T, you can just prepend it to the result:

```
var result = 'T' + date.split('T')[1]
```

Comment: This is assuming that `2015-12-22T17:44:24Z` is the entire string.

Comment: @ndn "parent strings like `2015-12-22T17:44:24Z`", I wouldn't overcomplicate the problem. Also, that's the string returned from the UTC date.